# Blazor Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, .net, blazor

I recently got into Blazor for web Dev as I'm trying to convert my website which was just php based. I am stuck in terms of trying to get data from my database. It is not empty.

In a DataAccessLibrary project I have:

SqlDataAccess.cs:

```
using Dapper;
using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DataAccessLibrary
{
    public class SqlDataAccess : ISqlDataAccess
    {
        private readonly IConfiguration _config;

        public string ConnectionStringName { get; set; } = "Default";

        public SqlDataAccess(IConfiguration config)
        {
            _config = config;
        }

        public async Task<List<T>> LoadData<T, U>(string sql, U parameters)
        {
            string connectionString = _config.GetConnectionString(ConnectionStringName);

            using (IDbConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                var data = await connection.QueryAsync<T>(sql, parameters);

                return data.ToList();
            }
        }

        public async Task SaveData<T>(string sql, T parameters)
        {
            string connectionString = _config.GetConnectionString(ConnectionStringName);

            using (IDbConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                await connection.ExecuteAsync(sql, parameters);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

ISqlDataAccess.cs:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DataAccessLibrary
{
    public interface ISqlDataAccess
    {
        string ConnectionStringName { get; set; }

        Task<List<T>> LoadData<T, U>(string sql, U parameters);
        Task SaveData<T>(string sql, T parameters);
    }
}
```

Db.cs:

```
using DataAccessLibrary.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DataAccessLibrary
{
    public class Db : IDb
    {
        private readonly ISqlDataAccess _db;

        public Db(ISqlDataAccess db)
        {
            _db = db;
        }

        public Task<List<Users>> SelectAll()
        {
            string sql = "SELECT * FROM dbo.users";

            return _db.LoadData<Users, dynamic>(sql, new { });
        }

        public Task Create(Users users)
        {
            string sql = @"INSERT INTO dbo.users (Dev, Username, BusinessName, Password, Token, Email, Phone, About, Address, City, Province, Latitude, Longitude, ProfilePicture, ProfileEmail, RegistrationNumber, Active, Business, Verified, Networkable, Premium, VerificationCode)
            (@Dev, @Username, @BusinessName, @Password, @Token, @Email, @Phone, @About, @Address, @City, @Province, @Latitude, @Longitude, @ProfilePicture, @ProfileEmail, @RegistrationNumber, @Active, @Business, @Verified, @Networkable, @Premium, @VerificationCode)";

            return _db.SaveData(sql, users);
        }
    }
}
```

IDb.cs:

```
using DataAccessLibrary.Models;

namespace DataAccessLibrary
{
    public interface IDb
    {
        Task Create(Users users);
        Task<List<Users>> SelectAll();
    }
}
```

In a folder called Models, I have a file called Users.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DataAccessLibrary.Models
{
    public class Users
    {
        public bool dev { get; set; }
        public string? username { get; set; }
    }
}
```

In my main project I placed the following code in Prigram.cs:

```
builder.Services.AddTransient<ISqlDataAccess, SqlDataAccess>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<IDb, Db>();
```

Furthermore, I have already included the ConnectString in appsettings.json.

In my index.razor file I do first call for the library:

```
@page "/Index"

@using DataAccessLibrary
@using DataAccessLibrary.Models
@inject IDb db

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h4>
   @users.Count
</h4>

@code{
    private List<Users> users;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        users = await db.SelectAll();
    }
}
```

When I run this, it gives me an error:

```
System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
```

Comment: Which line is it complaining about?

Comment: @LajosArpad It is complaining about the line on Index.razor file. the "@user.Count"

Comment: @LajosArpad I solved it, Since the users list is loaded asynchronously in the OnInitializedAsync method, it is null when the component initially renders.

Answer (score 0):

OK, your question isn't super clear, but I am looking on a phone... so.

The thing to remember is that the UI thread is seperate from the code thread and so I am guessing that you are fetching the data, but the UI thread is trying to access it before it is loaded.. hence it is null.
You need to put:

```
@if(object !=null)
 {
     do stuff
   }
```

In your page code... Then when your code has loaded the data,  you also need to refresh the page using this.statehaschanged() ...

You can do this using events in your data service and making a refresh function in your page code.

Sorry I can't go into more detail on my phone, if yr struggling come back and I'll find an example.

Good luck..